# How to migrate from manually compile sass to use webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader, webpack-style-loader, sass-loader

Recently I am working a react project in new company. The current development in local is using `node-sass-chokidar` pkg manually compile the scss files to css files. Here is the basic package json start scripts:

```
"build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
"start": "REACT_APP_DISABLE_FGAC=true npm-run-all -p watch-css format start-js",
```

Also all the css compiled the css files import to differnet js or jsx files.

I have added the webpack and `css-loader, style-loader, sass-loader` try to start it locally. But it is not working and always said `Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):`.

Any ideas what I should go on next to fix?